# Postgres(with prometheus storage adaptor) pg_stat_database shows zero values

Tags: postgresql, prometheus

We usea time series extension [prometheus storage adaptor](https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter) along with postgres to store prometheus data to Postgres.

We have a Prometheus [exporter](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter) to export Postgres metrics.
And it tries to get number of reads/writes to DB. Since values not showing up, I did following.

```html
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_database;
 datid |  datname  | numbackends | xact_commit | xact_rollback | blks_read | blks_hit | tup_returned | tup_fetched | tup_inserted | tup_updated | tup_deleted | conflicts | temp_files | temp_bytes | deadlocks | blk_read_time | blk_write_time | stats_reset
-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+-------------
     1 | template1 |           0 |           0 |             0 |         0 |        0 |            0 |           0 |            0 |           0 |           0 |         0 |          0 |          0 |         0 |             0 |              0 |
 12291 | template0 |           0 |           0 |             0 |         0 |        0 |            0 |           0 |            0 |           0 |           0 |         0 |          0 |          0 |         0 |             0 |              0 |
 12292 | postgres  |          12 |           0 |             0 |         0 |        0 |            0 |           0 |            0 |           0 |           0 |         0 |          0 |          0 |         0 |             0 |              0 |
(3 rows)
```

Specifically things like tup_fetched, tup_inserted etc shows zero values on 'postgres' database.

But I used following query to find current running queries on the DB.

```html
postgres=# select  pg_stat_activity.datname, pg_stat_activity.usename, pg_stat_activity.query from pg_stat_activity;
 datname  |      usename      |                                                   query
----------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          | postgres          |
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | psqladmin         | select * from pg_stat_database;
 postgres | postgres_exporter | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database;
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | postgres          | select  pg_stat_activity.datname, pg_stat_activity.usename, pg_stat_activity.query from pg_stat_activity;
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
 postgres | psqladmin         | COMMIT
          |                   |
          |                   |
          |                   |
(16 rows)
```

Unfortunately I could not see any WRITE per say, but COMMIT as you can see. I assume those are inserts ? But anyway we can see some select queries. So why not tup_fetched or tup_returned non zero ?

Has anyone came across this situation. Any ideas to tackle this issue?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the statistics collector. Is the process running? Are there messages in the log? Has IPv6 been disabled, but the statistics collector's UDP port is on IPv6?

Comment: [This](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/stale-statistics-cause-table-bloat/) might be relevant.

Comment: Laurenz, thanks for the prompt response.
I grep on current running processes, and could not find stat collector.

Comment: 08:42   0:00 postgres -csynchronous_commit=off
08:42   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
08:42   0:00 postgres: writer process
08:42   0:00 postgres: wal writer process
08:42   0:00 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher
08:42   0:16 postgres: psqladmin postgres x.x.x.x(36736) idle
08:44   0:00 postgres: postgres_exporter postgres x.x.x.x(53368) idle
08:50   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
0:10 /postgres_exporter --log.level=debug

Comment: I thought by default track_activities enabled. Then I went to postgres.conf and did following. Still the collector process not showing up.
track_activities = on
track_counts = on

Comment: Then there should be an error message in the PostgreSQL log when you restart the database server.

Comment: Actually I was running postgres on docker and I had to map container host to OS host(--net=host), with that, unfortunately localhost was not available inside container. Hence collector failing. Without your pointer, I could not have figured it out in a quick time!!!!!